# Assalamualaikum Why can a Muslim man marry a Christian a Jew but a Muslim woman cant do the same?

Tags: nikah

Why can a Muslim man marry a Christian a Jew but a Muslim woman do the same? Why is it forbidden for the woman but allowed for the man?

Comment: Because this is ordered by Allah in the qur'an further the permission for men is not general there are conditions that must be fulfilled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the stand of Islam on a Muslim woman marrying a non-believer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/544/whats-the-stand-of-islam-on-a-muslim-woman-marrying-a-non-believer)

Answer (score 0):

Muslim men may marry women who are of the "People of the Book," traditionally defined as Christians and Jews.  Muslim woman do not have the same option of marrying outside her faith.  This view is based on the Islamic role for men as heads of household who wield more power than women - a structure expected in Muslim societies.