# Is there a hadeeth about not promoting Muslim men marrying non-Muslim women?

Tags: nikah, source-identification, non-muslim

According to this Question - [Why are Muslim women prohibited from marrying non-Muslims while Muslim men are allowed to?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75/why-are-muslim-women-prohibited-from-marrying-non-muslims-while-muslim-men-are-a) muslim men can marry non muslim women.

But I had read a hadeeth which said that we must not promote this thing because the laws keep on getting diluted as time passes by i.e. now the muslim men might be converting their wives to Islam but maybe in later years they might not.

Can someone help me clarify this by finding that hadeeth?

Answer (score 1):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

I was not able to find any such hadees, only related ayah and hadees i found are felow:

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “A woman may be married for
>   four reasons: her wealth, her lineage, her beauty and her religious
>   commitment. **Choose the one who is religious**, may your hands be rubbed
>   with dust [i.e., may you prosper].”
>
> (Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 4802; Muslim, 1466).
>
> **Al-Nawawi said:**
>
> The correct meaning of this hadeeth is that the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) was describing what people usually
>   do, for they seek these four characteristics, the last of which in
>   their view is religious commitment, but you, **the one who is seeking
>   guidance, should look for a wife who is religious. But this is not an
>   absolute command.**
>
> This hadeeth encourages keeping company with people who are
>   religiously committed in all things, because the one who keeps company
>   with them will benefit from their good attitude and morals, their
>   blessing and their good ways, and he will be safe from mischief at
>   their hands.
>
> Sharh Muslim, 10/52

And ayah:

> “And do not marry Al-Mushrikaat (idolatresses) till they believe
>   (worship Allaah Alone). And indeed a slave woman who believes is
>   better than a (free) Mushrikah (idolatress), even though she pleases
>   you. And give not (your daughters) in marriage to Al‑Mushrikoon till
>   they believe (in Allaah Alone) and verily, a believing slave is better
>   than a (free) Mushrik (idolater), even though he pleases you. Those
>   (Al-Mushrikoon) invite you to the Fire, but Allaah invites (you) to
>   Paradise and forgiveness by His Leave, and makes His Ayaat (proofs,
>   evidences, verses, lessons, signs, revelations, etc.) clear to mankind
>   that they may remember”
>
> [al-Baqarah 2:221]

Although above ayah excludes ahlul-kitab, but this is somehow discouraged to marry any mushrik.

Now these are only closest what i found.

To read further why it is discouraged to marry non-muslims you can read [this](https://islamqa.info/en/20227) and also [this](https://islamqa.info/en/20884) fatwa.

### Allah knows best