# If a girl is a Christian and she reads/prays according to Bible - is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry her?

Tags: quran, nikah

I understand that a Muslim man can marry a woman from the people of the book (i.e Christian, Jew) but they should also be chaste (or repent sincerely) and of course, believe in God.

One question that came into my mind is, if she is a Christian and she reads/prays according to Bible - is it permissible to marry her? Of course we know it is better to marry a Muslim woman but what about for those where it may not be possible? What does Allah say about this situation/scenario?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marrying a non-muslim](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1539/marrying-a-non-muslim)

Answer (score 5):

> If a girl is a Christian and she reads/prays according to Bible - is it permissible for a Muslim man to marry her?

**Yes, it is permissible if she is chaste.**

Allah has permitted Muslims to marry Jewish and Christian woman, on condition that they are chaste and avoid unlawful sexual relations. He says in the Qur'an (what means):

> “Made lawful to you this day are At‑Tayyibaat [all kinds of Halaal
> (lawful) foods, which Allaah has made lawful (meat of slaughtered
> eatable animals, milk products, fats, vegetables and fruits)]. The
> food (slaughtered cattle, eatable animals) of the people of the
> Scripture (Jews and Christians) is lawful to you and yours is lawful
> to them.
>
> (Lawful to you in marriage) are chaste women from the
> believers and chaste women from those who were given the Scripture
> (Jews and Christians) before your time when you have given their due
> Mahr (bridal-money given by the husband to his wife at the time of
> marriage), desiring chastity (i.e. taking them in legal wedlock) not
> committing illegal sexual intercourse, nor taking them as girlfriends.
>
> And whosoever disbelieves in Faith, [i.e. in the Oneness of Allaah and
> in all the other Articles of Faith i.e. His (Allaah’s) Angels, His
> Holy Books, His Messengers, the Day of Resurrection and Al‑Qadar
> (Divine Preordainments)], then fruitless is his work; and in the
> Hereafter he will be among the losers”
>
> [Qur'an 5:5]

Answer (score 3):

It depends on her belief. If she associates others to God then she isn't lawful to you.

> Do not marry the females who set up partners (shirk) until they acknowledge. An acknowledging servant is better than one who sets up partners even if she attracts you. Do not also marry the males who set up partners until they acknowledge. An acknowledging servant is better than one who sets up partners even if s/he attracts you. These invite to the fire, while God is inviting to paradise and forgiveness by His leave. He clarifies His signs for the people that they may remember. 2:221