# Muslim man and Catholic woman

Tags: nikah, interfaith

Salam
my apologies for the question which seems to be similar to other questions but I am trying to be specific.

As a Muslim man, can I marry a practicing Catholic woman? She practices her faith, as I practice mine - does Allah allow this? I know that we are permitted to marry woman of "the book" provided they are chaste (or repented sincerely) and practicing which makes it lawful to Muslim men - but can she continue to practice her faith after a Nikah? We have spoken about children etc... and have pretty much "ironed" out the detail if we continue but as a Muslim man, I just need to know if Allah makes it permissible for me.

Sunni school of thought

Thank you.

Comment: How is this different from your question [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35462/if-a-girl-is-a-christian-and-she-reads-prays-according-to-bible-is-it-permissi)? An overall thought: if you have doubts so serious that you keep asking again and again for months, perhaps this is an indication that you aren't really comfortable with it. I may be overstepping boundaries here, and you haven't asked for advice, but if I were in your position, I would think hard whether I want to start a marriage with doubt.

Comment: I must agree in the last few months strictly speaking you asked no more than two or three real questions and repeated them changing just a irrelevant detail expecting new answers... that's not realy what this site is meant for!

Comment: Allah swt has allowed to marry the ahlul kitab but you have to keep these in mind that if she considers Prophet Jesus peace be upon him as a son of god then it would shirk and your kids would be following such faith too as mothers are the first teachers and there would be other consequences as well.

Comment: Thank you all. Sorry, you can say i am a little nervous but also very cautious obviously about Allah and what is permissible. that is all :)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have not came across any prohibition, in fact we are also reminded to be respectful to the people of "the book" in general when it comes to their belief.

But in general for such matter you may want to speak with people of knowledge on the subject and they might advise you personally if you have particular conditions which needs to be clarified. But the general consensus is that it is allowed.

But like any other marriage your judgement must be based on the righteousness of that person before the apparent beauty. **:-)**

Some reference to the subject

> https://islamqa.info/en/20227
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPrMkJHOhME