# New Muslim in need of help

Tags: halal-haram, relationships, parents

Truly there is no God but Allah and Allah is the creator and sustainer of all that existed, exists and can exist.

Asalamu Alaikum, I am a recent convert 2 months in April and I have one very big question. 
 
Before I reverted to Islam I had a girlfriend. We dated for 14 months before I broke up with her on terms of Islam. That should be the end of my question, right?

It's not. The reason for that is because my mother loves her. My mother is not a run-of-the-mill mother of a convert she actually has extensive Islamic knowledge and I'd say she's 5-salat-a-day, away from being a sheik etc.

Not only that I love this girl and she loves me back. I thought it was infatuation but it isn't. I made Isktikara and broke up with her and while I've brought her to my mosque a few times she's still on the fence about reverting.  I gave her space and told her to make own decision and she still wants to be with me and will accept the time away from me.

Is it permissible to speak to this female seeing as we had a relationship in hopes she'll convert as we were speaking before Islam and if not why not? 
Will it be enough to drop her even if it's at the expense of my mother's happiness?

Comment: you can maybe derive some results for you from this question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/can-a-muslim-man-marry-a-non-muslim-and-non-ahl-al-kitab-woman

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/can-a-muslim-man-marry-a-non-muslim-and-non-ahl-al-kitab-woman

Comment: you can speak, as long as you do not commit sin.

Answer (score -1):

According to what I've understood, you want to convince her to convert to Islam, but you're afraid that talking to her would be considered as a sin. Well, to be honest, there is no need to be afraid to talk to her in order to convince her. However, you should avoid being alone with her in some private place. You can suggest her to read a part of the Quran and discuss it in a public place. If you feel you'll be weak, you can contact her online (without cam) or you can introduce her to a female Muslim and pray she will be able to convince her. In any case, a non-Muslim woman could still be married by a Muslim man if they are Christians or Jewish (the people of the book). This is what I think and what I've understood.

May Allah bless you and help you.

Answer (score -2):

I was told if a man marrys a non Muslim girl it is okay because they are the one in choice of the religion of the children it is not completely haram to marry her but Allah would me more pleased with you if you where to marry a Muslim female.Also try to tell her benefits of islam.

Comment: Answers beginning with "I was told" don't fit to the SE policy's. I strongly suggest you to learn more about how this site works by taking the tour http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour visiting our help-center http://islam.stackexchange.com/help