# Is conversion mandatory for a muslim boy to marry a hindu girl?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim, conversion, hindu

Is it necessary for a hindu girl to convert to islam to marry a muslim guy? Considering that conversion to any religion is not to be forced on any person, how can this marriage happen? Is there a way to marry the guy as a hindu girl in a nikkah ceremony? Please help.
The girl does not want to convert in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Muslim man marry a non-Muslim (and non-Ahl-al-Kitab) woman?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23497/can-a-muslim-man-marry-a-non-muslim-and-non-ahl-al-kitab-woman)

Answer (score 0):

Muslim are not permissible to marry polytheists.
If the Hindu girl don't want to convert then my best opinion will be to leave her and let her be.

2:221
وَلَا تَنكِحُوا۟ ٱلْمُشْرِكَـٰتِ حَتَّىٰ يُؤْمِنَّ ۚ وَلَأَمَةٌۭ مُّؤْمِنَةٌ خَيْرٌۭ مِّن مُّشْرِكَةٍۢ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَتْكُمْ ۗ وَلَا تُنكِحُوا۟ ٱلْمُشْرِكِينَ حَتَّىٰ يُؤْمِنُوا۟ ۚ وَلَعَبْدٌۭ مُّؤْمِنٌ خَيْرٌۭ مِّن مُّشْرِكٍۢ وَلَوْ أَعْجَبَكُمْ ۗ أُو۟لَـٰٓئِكَ يَدْعُونَ إِلَى ٱلنَّارِ ۖ وَٱللَّهُ يَدْعُوٓا۟ إِلَى ٱلْجَنَّةِ وَٱلْمَغْفِرَةِ بِإِذْنِهِۦ ۖ وَيُبَيِّنُ ءَايَـٰتِهِۦ لِلنَّاسِ لَعَلَّهُمْ يَتَذَكَّرُونَ ٢٢١

Do not marry polytheistic women until they believe; for a believing slave-woman is better than a free polytheist, even though she may look pleasant to you. And do not marry your women to polytheistic men until they believe, for a believing slave-man is better than a free polytheist, even though he may look pleasant to you. They invite ˹you˺ to the Fire while Allah invites ˹you˺ to Paradise and forgiveness by His grace. He makes His revelations clear to the people so perhaps they will be mindful.
— Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran

2:256
لَآ إِكْرَاهَ فِى ٱلدِّينِ ۖ قَد تَّبَيَّنَ ٱلرُّشْدُ مِنَ ٱلْغَىِّ ۚ فَمَن يَكْفُرْ بِٱلطَّـٰغُوتِ وَيُؤْمِنۢ بِٱللَّهِ فَقَدِ ٱسْتَمْسَكَ بِٱلْعُرْوَةِ ٱلْوُثْقَىٰ لَا ٱنفِصَامَ لَهَا ۗ وَٱللَّهُ سَمِيعٌ عَلِيمٌ ٢٥٦

Let there be no compulsion in religion, for the truth stands out clearly from falsehood. So whoever renounces false gods and believes in Allah has certainly grasped the firmest, unfailing hand-hold. And Allah is All-Hearing, All-Knowing.
— Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran

You can't force someone to follow Islam when they don't believe in Allah A.Z.W .
My best Advice here for you is to choose a Muslim women who is in need of your help.