# Is there any reference from Islamic teachings that Hinduism is considered as “polytheistic religion”?

Tags: islamic-philosophy

Sorry for such a long question description, but it became long due to several citations.
In short, **Why there is misconception of considering Hinduism as “polytheistic religion and why it is still being considered? Anything stated in Islamic philosophy?**

I would like to state some of the facts I have found:

1. Myths that most of them believe in Hinduism by others, that there are 330 million Hindu gods, hence calling it as “polytheism” which is totally wrong. Read the myth number 1 & even 2 from this [source](http://religion.blogs.cnn.com/2014/04/25/9-myths-about-hinduism-debunked/)
2. In short, there are similarities between Hinduism and Islam which you can refer from [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu%E2%80%93Islamic_relations) and [here on Quora](https://www.quora.com/in/What-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-Islam-and-Hinduism) which states “The authentic scriptures of both religions teaches monotheism”.
3. It’s not yet cleared till now that Hinduism is a polytheistic religion [read from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_views_on_monotheism). Instead there are proofs that Hinduism is a monotheistic religion according to the sacred books which can be referred from [here](http://www.aryasamaj.com/enews/2014/jan/6.htm)

I’m trying to get this answer because in a previous answer to my question where it was said that according to Quran 2:221 says that the Qur'an directly forbids marriage to a polytheist.

1. Even in addition, some countries like [Tunisia](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-41278610) and especially India according to Special Marriage Act, 1954 allows inter-religion marriages according to the abiding laws. Then why not it is acceptable in the religion itself?
2. Even here it was asked that [Does the Qur'an prohibit Muslim women from marrying non-Muslim men or just Jews and Christians?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25721/does-the-quran-prohibit-muslim-women-from-marrying-non-muslim-men-or-just-jews) says that “The majority of scholars say that Muslim men are allowed to marry Christian and Jews” according to the People of the Book. Additionally stated that “In later Islamic usage, the use of the term was later extended to even polytheistic Indians".

Also, it was said “The final point which many will argue against is a Muslim woman marrying Christian/Jew. Sadly there is no proof from Quran and Sunnah to back that up, but still many scholars would say it is not allowed.”

But, in another thread asking [Why are Muslim women prohibited from marrying non-Muslims while Muslim men are allowed to?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/75/why-are-muslim-women-prohibited-from-marrying-non-muslims-while-muslim-men-are-a) it says it is prohibited according to Quran 60:10 due to disbelievers but it’s nowhere stated that Hindus are disbelievers.

At last, in Book 46, Hadith 37 says

> No baby is born but upon Fitra. It is his parents who make him a Jew or a Christian or a Polytheist.

Comment: Relevant: [What's the stand of Islam on a Muslim woman marrying a non-believer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/544)

Comment: I asked this question because there's [recent noticeable national incident appeared in news](http://www.india.com/news/india/tina-dabi-weds-athar-aamir-ul-shafi-khan-how-the-ias-couple-overcame-love-jihad-accusations-and-turned-their-story-into-a-beautiful-wedding-2989584/) where they broke the stereotype and got married.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism#Concept_of_God) is loosely defined. We don't go about arguing what certain ancient Hindu scriptures "really teach", we consider what most Hindus believe. For the majority it does involve idolatry and polytheism, which is *Shirk*. For some it is monaltry\henotheism, which is again *shirk*. For some it may be monotheistic.

Even if we only consider truly monotheistic ones, it isn't permissible to marry them since permission to marry in Islam is on a white-list basis. The Quran explicitly only allows marriage to those non-Muslims who were given a Scripture by Allah:

> والمحصنات من المؤمنات والمحصنات من الذين **أوتوا الكتاب من قبلكم**
>
> chaste women from among the believers and chaste women from among **those who were given the Scripture before you**
>
> <sup>— [Quran 5:5](https://quran.com/5/5)</sup>

There is no tradition within Islam that holds that Hindus were given a scripture. According to most, the *people of the book* are only two groups: the Jews and Christians, based on [6:156](https://quran.com/6/156).

---

Muslim *women* are not allowed to marry *all* disbelievers:

> فلا ترجعوهن الى **الكفار** لا هن حل لهم ولا هم يحلون لهن
>
> do not return them to the **disbelievers**; they are not lawful [wives] for them, nor are they lawful [husbands] for them.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 60:10](https://quran.com/60/10)</sup>

Regarding your comment that:

```
it’s nowhere stated that Hindus are disbelievers
```

Disbelievers (Kuffar) means non-Muslims. The definition of a believer is enumerated in for example:

> يا أيها الذين آمنوا آمنوا بالله ورسوله والكتاب الذي نزل على رسوله والكتاب الذي أنزل من قبل ومن يكفر بالله وملائكته وكتبه ورسله واليوم الآخر فقد ضل ضلالا بعيدا
>
> O you who have believed, believe in Allah and His Messenger and the Book that He sent down upon His Messenger and the Scripture which He sent down before. And whoever disbelieves in Allah, His angels, His books, His messengers, and the Last Day has certainly gone far astray.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:136](https://quran.com/4/136)</sup>

Do Hindus believe that "There is no god except Allah" and everything else is His creation and servant (the Shadah)?

Do Hindus believe in the Prophethood of Muhammad (ﷺ) and the previous Prophets and Messengers like Jesus, Moses, Abraham (عليهم السلام اجمعين
) etc.?

Do they believe in the Divine revelation of the Torah, Psalms, Injeel and Quran ?

Do they follow the commandments of the Quran and the Prophet?

Do the believe in the angels like Gabriel, Michael, Israfil ?

Do they believe in the Day of Resurrection?

If they do then they are believers and Muslims, and there is no obstacle in marrying them. If they deny or are not clear on even one of these then they are disbelievers.

Comment: According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People_of_the_Book#Later_Islamic_usage), says many of the Muslim clergy of India considered Hindus as people of the book. Secondly, if all non-Muslims are disbelievers; then Christians and Jews also are disbelievers because there are references in bible itself where Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is interpreted as "false prophet". Lastly, I and most of them believe that there is one god but it is not specifically named as "Allah" anywhere. It's us who name the god, Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) was the messenger of god.

Comment: @Anonymous Wikipedia isn't a reliable source and "many" is immensely vague ... inevitably some rogue scholar somewhere may say whatever they want, it doesn't make it a significant view, nor the view of a majority. Jews and Christians ARE disbelievers too, and Muslim women can not marry them, Muslim men can marry Jewish\Christian women, because 5:5 makes an exception for them. Partial disbelief is also disbelief, denying that Allah is God's name is *Kufr* of the Quran and the Prophet ... I've no desire to debate your beliefs with you, Islam.SE is meant for answers on Islamic doctrine.

Comment: I know that the fact of a Muslim Men can marry in an exceptional case, but i.e. temporary marriage (mut'ah) according to [Quran 4:24](https://quran.com/4/24) which should be banned but unfortunately the practice is still followed. I can say that my statement is not a "kufr". Understand the context, I'm not even disrespecting anyone, indeed I said the universal truth that God is one and monotheism states the same. There are [99 names](https://muflihun.com/muslim/35/6475) of "Allah" according to Book 35 Hadith 6475 and have respect for all his names. I couldn't complete my statement earlier.

Comment: @Anonymous *Mutah* is permitted in Shiism, your opinion on the matter is irrelevant; infact I don't even see the relevance of this to this question.

Comment: It is relevant to the question because how a disbeliever is allowed to get married whereas polytheism marriage is forbidden and I'm happy to know that the question is being down-voted. Long live community.

Comment: @Anonymous A disbeliever man is never allowed to marry a Muslim woman, *Mutah* or otherwise. A disbeliever, but Jewish or Christian, woman is allowed to marry a Muslim man.

Comment: Okay, I wouldn't led the conflict go ahead cause I had recently got a beautiful answer by a person for which the answer has been recently deleted. It's my fault asking these questions because nothing can change the past and the consequences are clearly visible ahead. Thanks for your kind time.

Comment: @Anonymous The purpose of the site is to learn about Islamic doctrine from authoritative and reliable sources. If your aim here was to engage in debate and convince someone to change their views or to bring about social change, then you are in the wrong place.